# I am not looking for data in the database using JS vanilla

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I am doing a class exercise which I must do with XMLHTTPREQUEST and JSON, we cannot use Jquery.

The thing is that we must look for concrete data through inputs created by us. When I do the search, I get this error, and I don't know how to solve it

exercise1.js: 146 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
    at exercise1.js: 146
    at Array.forEach ()
    at drawTable (exercise1.js: 138)
    at XMLHttpRequest.peticion.onreadystatechange (exercise1.js: 125)

We must put the data in an array and then put it in the table

```
// Añade todo el código que creas necesario para que la aplicación funcione.
// Debes respetar las funciones indicadas, programando en ellas la funcionalidad que se indica


// Usa el siguiente arrya global para almacenar los empleados cada vez que haces una consulta
var misEmpleados = new Array();

window.addEventListener("load", crearFormularioBusqueda);
// Usa la siguiente función para crear mediante DOM el contenido del formulario de búsqueda de empleados (id="formularioBusqueda")
// Deberá tener un input de tipo texto para apellidos, nombre, departamento y telefono, otro de tipo
// fecha para la fecha de alta y un botón para realizar la búsqueda mediante el manejador buscar definido más adelante.
// Identifica los input con un Label. 
function crearFormularioBusqueda() // 1 punto
{
    form = document.getElementById("formularioBusqueda");
    var salto = document.createElement("br");
    var input_codigo = document.createElement('input');
    var label_codigo = document.createElement('label');
    input_codigo.setAttribute("type", "text");
    input_codigo.setAttribute("placeholder", "Codigo");
    input_codigo.setAttribute("name", "codigo");
    form.appendChild(input_codigo);
    form.appendChild(salto);

    var input_nombre = document.createElement('input');
    input_nombre.setAttribute("type", "text");
    input_nombre.setAttribute("placeholder", "Nombre");
    input_nombre.setAttribute("name", "nombre");
    form.appendChild(input_nombre);
    form.appendChild(salto);

    var input_apellidos = document.createElement('input');
    input_apellidos.setAttribute("type", "text");
    input_apellidos.setAttribute("placeholder", "Apellidos");
    input_apellidos.setAttribute("name", "apellidos");
    form.appendChild(input_apellidos);
    form.appendChild(salto);

    var input_departamento = document.createElement('input');
    input_departamento.setAttribute("type", "text");
    input_departamento.setAttribute("placeholder", "Departamento");
    input_departamento.setAttribute("name", "departamento");
    form.appendChild(input_departamento);
    form.appendChild(salto);

    var input_telefono = document.createElement('input');
    input_telefono.setAttribute("type", "number");
    input_telefono.setAttribute("placeholder", "Telefono");
    input_telefono.setAttribute("name", "telefono");
    form.appendChild(input_telefono);
    form.appendChild(salto);

    var input_fecha = document.createElement('input');
    input_fecha.setAttribute("type", "date");
    input_fecha.setAttribute("placeholder", "Fecha Alta");
    input_fecha.setAttribute("name", "Fecha_alta");
    form.appendChild(input_fecha);
    form.appendChild(salto);

    var cargar = document.createElement("input");
    cargar.setAttribute("type", "button");
    cargar.setAttribute("value", "cargar");
    cargar.setAttribute("name", "cargar");
    cargar.setAttribute("title", "cargar");
    form.appendChild(cargar);
    form.appendChild(salto);
    cargar.addEventListener('click', function() {
        buscar();
    });



    var insertar = document.createElement("input");
    insertar.setAttribute("type", "button");
    insertar.setAttribute("value", "insertar");
    insertar.setAttribute("name", "insertar");
    insertar.setAttribute("title", "insertar");
    form.appendChild(insertar);
    form.appendChild(salto);




}


// Este manejador controlará el evento click del botón buscar creado previamente
// Se encargará de la consulta AJAX usando el archivo empleados_json.php del lado del servidor.
function buscar() // 1,5 puntos
{
    tablaSalida.innerHTML = '<tr><th>Codigo</th><th>Nombre</th><th>Apellidos</th><th>Departamento</th><th>Telefono</th><th>Fecha</th></tr>';

    var peticion = new XMLHttpRequest();

    peticion.open('GET', '../servidor/empleados_json.php');
    peticion.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    peticion.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (peticion.readyState == 4 && peticion.status == 200) {
            misEmpleados = new Array();
            console.log(peticion.responseText);
            var respuesta = JSON.parse(peticion.responseText);
            for (var i = 0; i < respuesta.length; i++) {
                var codigo = respuesta[i].codigo;
                var nombre = respuesta[i].nombre;
                var apellidos = respuesta[i].apellidos;
                var departamento = respuesta[i].departamento;
                var telefono = respuesta[i].telefono;
                var fecha_alta = respuesta[i].fecha_alta;


                var elEmpleado = new Empleado();
                elEmpleado.setCodigo(codigo);
                elEmpleado.setNombre(nombre);
                elEmpleado.setApellidos(apellidos);
                elEmpleado.setDepartamento(departamento);
                elEmpleado.setTelefono(telefono);
                elEmpleado.setFechaAlta(fecha_alta);


                misEmpleados.push(elEmpleado);
            }
            dibujarTabla();
        }

    };
    peticion.send();
}


// La siguiente función dibujará en la tabla de salida (id="tablaSalida") el resultado de cada consulta a la base de datos
// Limpia las búsquedas anteriores para que no se acumulen.
function dibujarTabla() // 1 punto
{
    var tabla = document.getElementById("cuerpoTabla");
    misEmpleados.forEach(function(empleado) {
        var elemento = document.createElement("tr");
        elemento.innerHTML += ("<td>" + empleado.getCodigo() + "</td>");
        elemento.innerHTML += ("<td>" + empleado.getNombre() + "</td>");
        elemento.innerHTML += ("<td>" + empleado.getApellidos() + "</td>");
        elemento.innerHTML += ("<td>" + empleado.getDepartamento() + "</td>");
        elemento.innerHTML += ("<td>" + empleado.getTelefono() + "</td>");
        elemento.innerHTML += ("<td>" + empleado.getFechaAlta() + "</td>");
        tabla.appendChild(elemento);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `let` before `form`, so that variable is never declared.

```js
function crearFormularioBusqueda() // 1 punto
{
    let form = document.getElementById("formularioBusqueda");
    var salto = document.createElement("br");
    ...
```